# React Flow: Cannot resolve module react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I have started a React Native project from scratch and configured Flow.

When I run `npm run flow` everything works fine except a small problem with the `react-native` module:

> Cannot resolve module react-native.

I am using:

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.3",
"flow-bin": "0.74.0"
```

My **.flowconfig** is:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
.*/.cache/.*
.*/test/.*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]

[strict]
```

Tried with `"flow-typed": "2.4.0"` but didn't work.

I found the following [issue](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode/issues/215) but there aren't any solutions :/

Comment: Did you used . create-react-app tool to create seeds and then after did npm i somepack?

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using Expo.

Comment: even you used Expo but did you follow above step?

Comment: No, that all. I am using the Flow extension for Visual Studio Code but I don't think this makes sense.

Comment: I initialized blank expo app, installed `flow-bin`, initialized empty `.flowconfig` file, added `@flow` to `App.js` and executed `npx flow` - everything seems to be working. Have I missed anything to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo, nope :(

Comment: I did, check this .flowconfig and see if works for you.  https://textuploader.com/dzfet

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Sad, I had 4 hours of pure hate yesterday, luckily this worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a type definition for `react-native`.

Create a folder called `type-def-lib` in your project root and inside create a file called `react-native.js` with these contents

```
declare module 'react-native' {
  declare module.exports: any
}
```

Then in your `.flowconfig` add that folder under libs:

```
[libs]
./type-def-libs
```

Now `yarn run flow` should produce no errors.

Comment: What does this actually do? Thanks!

Comment: it provides a "libdef" for the react-native module, I am not sure why it works at all as libdefs are not necessary but you can read the documentation about the process here: https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/ as far as I know, flow does the exact process above automatically for all librarys that do not have type declarations (setting them to any) so I'm gonna assume that the current react native flow type declaration has some sort of bug and this explicit any declaration overrides that.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version `flow-bin` (0.157.0), this problem can be resolved by removing `.*/node_modules/.*` from `[ignore]`